# MSMQ client support for linux

Tags: queue, jms, msmq

I have a use case where MSMQ server is running in our clients infrastructure and we have to receive messages sent by them on the MSMQ queue. I know MSMQ is a windows based system and will work best with windows but is there a way I can just get the messages in Linux ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: Unless you can find a 3rd party product, you'll need to write an MSMQ client to run on Linux. The APIs are documented so it's possible but not something you would consider unless you really had to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to solve it is to bridge to some multi platform messaging product. ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ or whatnot. For that you probably need to write a small bridge service on a Windows server. So that all messages are relayed through "the multi platform broker".

Comment: That's what I am planning to do. I am planing to write a C# application on windows which receives data from client's MSMQ and forward that to ActiveMQ running on a linux host(Using ActiveMQ's NMS APis). And another consumer application which receives data from ActiveMQ on linux and process that. Let me know if this solution looks good or do you see any better way ?

Comment: I've seen that exact solution running just fine. You should be good.